# Suppress output, keep pander and plot in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have the following code in my Rmd file:

```
library(randomForestSRC)
library(ggRandomForests)
rf_all <- rfsrc(Y ~ ., data=df, block.size=1, ntree=100, importance=TRUE)
plot(gg_vimp(vimp.rfsrc(rf_all))) + theme(legend.position = "none") 
rf_select <- var.select.rfsrc(rf_all)
pander(rf_select$varselect)
confmat <- confusionMatrix (rf_all$class.oob, data$Enddiagnosegruppe)
pander(confmat$table)
```

I'm trying to create an HTML report, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what chunk options to use such that:

1. The output of the rfsrc functions is suppressed.
2. All the plots appear.
3. The calls to pander yield properly formatted output.

I have tried pretty much all combinations of chunk options for message, warnings, error, as well as wrapping parts of my code in invisible(), capture.output(), as well as playing around with panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE). Nothing seems to work, either the messages are not suppressed, pander tables look weird, empty section headers appear out of nowhere (I'm guessing "##" is inserted somewhere), no luck. I feel like I'm missing the forest for the trees here. Not to mention that this code is supposed to be wrapped in a loop that generates different formulae. Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: would you mind to make this more reproducible, i.e. copy-paste-and-immediately-runable best of all? see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried breaking the code chunk up and have the plot be your last chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following works:

```
rf_select <- var.select.rfsrc(rf_all, verbose=FALSE)
cat("\n")
pander(rf_select$varselect)
```

The problem is that var.select.rfsrc() uses cat() instead of message(), and somehow adding a newline is necessary since otherwise the first pander table is run together with the previous line in the markdown file.